# Insert JavaScript Variable in PHP Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have a problem with a code... I have a javascript variable and want to insert it into a PHP array parameter... 
This is the code:

```
function visible(dato) { 
    var imagen;
    //var name;
    imagen =  "<? echo $ItemID[DATO][img] ?>";
    obj = document.getElementById("MenuItem");
    document.getElementById("retrato").src="/items/" + imagen + ".png";
    //document.getElementById("titulo").innerHTML="<titulo>" + name + "</titulo>";
    obj.style.display = "block";
}
```

I want to insert the variable "DATO" parameter in php

Comment: You can't. Use AJAX instead

Comment: even in a million years we will still be pointing out this fundamental difference

Comment: Works only the other way around, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

This MAY accomplish what you are trying to do, BUT you really need to learn the difference between client and server side.You MAY be able to do this:

```
imagen =  <?=json_encode($ItemID); ?>;
imagen = imagen[data].img;
```